# jQuery: POST data animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I'm getting data with AJAX like this:

```
$.post("ajaxLog.php", {func: 'getAllChallenges', arr: array}, function(data){
    $(".mainpageAppending").prepend(data);
    $(".mainpageChallengeResponseDiv").css('display', 'none');

    $(data).filter(".mainpageChallengeDiv").toggle(function(){
        $(data).filter(".mainpageChallengeDiv").slideToggle();
    });

    tmout = setTimeout("intervalLoading()", 10000);
});
```

I need to do animation of prepended data with `.mainpageChallengeDiv`. Everything is OK, but that animation doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it is maybe impossible so I started thinking about Server side, and work it when I set it opacity 0 and all divs animating with animate opacity 1. Anyway thanks, but if is there solutions to lower traffic of web browser so I'm in with that solution.